# TURN server connection fails while trying to connect via SimpleWebRTC

Tags: webrtc, simplewebrtc, coturn, signalmaster

I'm trying to make videochat app using SimpleWebRTC, Signalmaster and Coturn.

On the webpage everything works fine when I try to connect from one tab to another in same browser or over LAN. I'm encountering problems while connecting between computers in different networks (wired broadband and 3G in my case).

I did set up signaling server (Signalmaster) with following config for STUN/TURN part:

```
"stunservers": [
    {
      "urls": "stun:mydomain.com:3478"
    }
  ],
  "turnservers": [
    {
      "urls": ["turn:mydomain.com:3478"],
      "secret": "secretword",
      "expiry": 3600
    }
  ]
```

It works since browsers connect to STUN server and exchange signaling data. But when it comes to TURN functionality, Chrome silently fails and Firefox says that my TURN server is likely broken. My Coturn config (let's assume server ip is 1.2.3.4 and domain is mydomain.com):

```
listening-ip=1.2.3.4
use-auth-secret
static-auth-secret=secretword
realm=mydomain.com
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow the "WEBRTC USAGE" instructions in README.turnserver, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I do follow it as far as I understand. It's quite short section, so I think I understood it.

Comment: Well I don't see the long term credentials and fingerprinting options in your config file (unless they're specified on the command line).

Comment: Signalmaster signaling server doesn't support long term credential mechanism. I will read about fingerprinting and try enabling it. Thanks.